# Sharing Customer and Session between 2 sites

Tags: magento-1.7, migration

I am very new to magento and i have two sites  abc.com , bcd.com hosted on different server. 
Now i want when user will do checkout on bcd.com , it will redirect to abc.com and user can make payment. after sucess payment it will redirect back to bcd.com. 
Can any body tell me how to achieve this result

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to be able to pass details between the two sites.  I'd have thought that you could produce a custom API to pass order information from one system to the other - I'm assuming site BCD.com isn't a Magento store and is just a payment gateway, so this is certainly achievable (things like Sagepay FORMs uses this exact method).

EDIT:
As both sites ARE Magento stores:

Assuming the domains are not subdomains of each other, I think this would be fairly complex to achieve (if they were, you could use the domain cookie to share at least session data between them). You'd essentially need to create an API to send customer, cart & checkout information from one site to the other, and then back again.

Comment: its a magento store

Comment: both websites are in magento

Comment: Could you please give me idea how to do this.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Could you please give me some basic idea. i m totllay new in magento